# How to invoke a matlab function from mathematica?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I would like to call a matlab function from mathematica.  How best to do that?

I have found an [ancient post on Wolfram site](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/618/) describing a way to do this, is this still the way to connect the two?

Comment: +1 I'd love to know how to do this too, some things are easier in Matlab and some things are easier in Mathematica!

Comment: John, have you tried the other answer I posted in May 2013?

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope, you posted after I had moved onto a new job, where I just use Matlab.  I have mathematica at home, but haven't needed to do this kind of cross scripting at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mEngine](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4821/).  The precompiled Windows MathLink executable works with Mathematica 8.  On Windows you may need to [add MATLAB to the system path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326258/install-mathlink-program-with-arbitrary-path-environment).

The advantage of this compared to the NETLink method is that transferring variables between Mathematica and MATLAB will be as easy as `mGet["x"]` or `mPut["x"]`.  Although this might be possible with NETLink too, the advantage of mEngine is that you don't  need to implement it yourself (which is great if like me you don't know anything about COM or .NET)

Comment: Please see [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16329357/695132) about [MATLink](http://matlink.org).  MATLink was inspired by mEngine and is far superior to it (in functionality and reliability).

Answer (score 6):

You can try `NETLink` for this at least under Windows:

```
In[1]:= Needs["NETLink`"]
matlab = CreateCOMObject["matlab.application"]

Out[2]= «NETObject[COMInterface[MLApp.DIMLApp]]»
```

And then you can invoke Matlab functions:

```
In[4]:= matlab@Execute["version"]

Out[4]= "
ans =

7.9.0.529 (R2009b)

"

In[5]:= matlab@Execute["a=2"]

matlab@Execute["a*2"]

Out[5]= "
a =

     2

"

Out[6]= "
ans =

     4

"
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that this is a difficult problem in general, but can be easily solved with a little programming for a particular case. I'll demonstrate with C#.

I would build a string of calls, like so.

- Mathematica calls a C# program, through *MathLink*. This is near trivial to setup, and Mathematica has a sample project in *Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Links\NETLink* directory.
- C# program calls Matlab. There are several ways to make this call, and [this handy link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12987-integrating-matlab-with-c) describes how to do it and offers sample code.
- C# program returns Matlab results.

All in all I could do this in less than 50 lines of C# code, for a specific problem. Not too much work, in other words. Possible problems are data conversion, but if you want to send back and forth arrays of data, *MathLink* offers a lot out of the box. Similarly Mathematica can be linked to MATLAB through Java, though I haven't done that myself.

Perhaps the easiest connection could be made through Python. Mathematica offers an installable *MathLink* python library, located at *Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Links\NETLink*, and Matlab has an addon library called PyMat, which can be downloaded [here](http://pymat.sourceforge.net/), but this package hasn't been maintained for a long time and supports only the most ancient of Matlabs.

Alternatively you can forgo Matlab altogether in favor of SAGE and/or numpy.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new package for this --- [MATLink](http://rsmenon.github.io/MATLink/).  It is the most complete such package I am aware of.  (Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of MATLink.)

MATLink lets you ...

- seamlessly call MATLAB functions form Mathematica
- transfer data between the two systems

Most MATLAB data types are supported, including sparse arrays, structs and cells.

A more complete description is available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24478/12).  For detailed examples, see the [website](http://rsmenon.github.io/MATLink/).