# Non-windows way to invoke Matlab from Mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

This was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510770/how-to-invoke-a-matlab-function-from-mathematica), but the solution doesn't seem to work on MacOS. Wolfram Library [has a package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/618/) for 7 year old Matlab version. Is there a solution that works on MacOS 10.6 and Matlab 7.9?

I want to call [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) from Mathematica

Comment: I've only tried invoking mma from Matlab using the Mathematica Symbolic Toolbox on Mathworks FileExchange, so I don't have an answer for you.  That being said, both Matlab and Mathematica integrate pretty well with Java; in particular, calling Java classes from Mathematica is very easy.  Perhaps JMI (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/) on Matlab's side combined with JLink on mma side could do the trick...

Comment: Calling Java classes from Matlab is also very easy, other way round is hard. I've had some success with Matlab Builder JA, but this meant making a wrapper for every Matlab function I wanted to call from outside

Comment: I hope you find something easier, but in case everything else fails, you'll have to code your own solution. I can feel your pain, I'm facing a similar problem, where there are no official packages for connecting the 2 applications I'm interested in. Try this Wikipedia page for a summary of [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods.

Comment: Take a look at [MATLink](http://rsmenon.github.io/MATLink/). :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `RunThrough["command",expr]`, this runs the external command `command`, and feeds `expr` (a Mathematica expression) as input to `command`

An example of a suitable command would be `"matlab -r \"matlab expr\""`, you could place your CVX specific code in the "matlab expr" string.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**  Right now, probably [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) is the best way to do this. It works on Windows/Linux/Mac.

<sup>Disclosure: I'm one of MATLink's authors.</sup>

---

Have you tried using the newer [mEngine](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4821/) instead?  I can only try it on Windows, but after looking at the sources, I believe it might work on other platforms too.

Hopefully you only need to modify `main.c`, actually just copy and paste the main function from one of the MathLink examples (e.g. addtwo), as mEngine's `main.c` has the non-Windows-specific part removed.  [Then compile the package as a MathLink program.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkDeveloperGuide-Macintosh.html#13362)

Comment: Wow, thanks for bringing Matlink to my attention.  Looks promising, I'll give it a whirl soon.  I probably shouldn't upvote this answer for the as-yet-untried benefits of Matlink, but I am doing so anyway.