# Install MathLink program with arbitrary PATH environment

Tags: interop, wolfram-mathematica, environment-variables, mathlink

Is it possible to use `Install[]` to start a MathLink program with a custom `PATH` environment variable?

I am trying to use [**mEngine**](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4821/) to connect Mathematica to MATLAB on Windows.  It only works if `mEngine.exe` is launched when the `PATH` environment variable includes the path to the MATLAB libraries.  Is it possible to modify the PATH for launching this program *only*, without needing to modify the system path?  Or is there another way to launch `mEngine.exe`?

Comment: this is on windows, I suppose?

Comment: @acl yes, I'll update the question.

Comment: while I have never used windows, I vaguely remember that DOS has batch files. so could you not start mEngine from a batch file that temporarily redefines the path, then reverts?

Comment: @acl Yes, this works very well ... I don't know why I had the idea that we should pass `Install` the MathLink executable and not a script that starts it ...  I wonder if I should delete this question now.

Comment: @Szabolcs well, I'd leave it. I'm sure you're not the first or last to have this problem and simply not think of the answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs -- There is a *Mathematica* function `Environment[name]` which allows you to read the kernel's shell variable `name`. But there is no *Mathematica* function for setting environment variables (such as `SetEnvironment[name,value]`). Is this what you are after?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I'd try acl's answer and see if it works. If it does, encourage him to post it as an answer.

Comment: @rcollyer you could also construct a batch file and use `setx` to set a global env PATH var. So, first run that batch, then install your program, and after that run another batch file that removes the added directories from %path%

Comment: @acl Yes, as, rcollyer said, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @belisarius I didn't know about `setx`.  It doesn't seem to be available on all versions of Windows (not on this XP at least).  But `set` works well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wouldn't know what to put in my answer. Last time I wrote batch programs for non-unix systems was on DOS 3.3. Maybe you can answer yourself with the solution you used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@acl's solution to wrap mEngine.exe in a batch file, and temporarily modify the PATH from there, works correctly:

I used this as the contents of `mEngine.bat`:

```
set PATH=c:\path\to\matlab\bin\win32;%PATH%
start mEngine.exe %*
```

- `*%` ensures that all command line arguments are passed on to `mEngine.exe`
- `start` is necessary to prevent the command window from staying open until `mEngine.exe` terminates

It can be started using `Install["mEngine.bat"]`.

Since all the information that is needed for the kernel to communicate with `mEngine.exe` is passed by `Install[]` as command line arguments, all we need to do is launch `mEngine.exe` with these arguments.  It is not necessary for `Install[]` to know the location of `mEngine.exe`, the important thing is that the process gets launched with the correct command line arguments, which is ensured by `%*`.

Comment: Good to know, never occurred to me. +1.

Comment: @acl I do realize for UNIX folks it's part of the fundamentals!  Plus, probably there it wouldn't be necessary to give the matlab path at all

Comment: @Szabolcs I really was just jokingly referring to "acl's solution"!